# Text and Image relative responsive using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on responsiveness of web page, for that I am using Bootstrap.

The web page consists of both image and text. I am able to make both of them responsive, but the image is getting responsive separately of the text. Both are not relative to each other.

I mean if an `img` is there after 5 lines of text, it is moving to some other place, but it's size is decreasing. How can I make both text and image relatively responsive?

```
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
            <img src="live_files/img_01.svg" class='img-responsive "stl_01"'>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
            <div class="stl_02">
                <span class="stl_03">Browser Support </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
            <div class="stl_04">
                <span class="stl_05">For PC users, LiveBinders is compatible
                    with Firefox 21 and higher, Safari 4.0.5 and higher, </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
            <div class="stl_06">
                <span class="stl_05">Chrome 30 and higher, and I.E. 9.0 and
                    higher. </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
            <div class="stl_07">
                <span class="stl_05">For Mac users, LiveBinders is
                    compatible with Safari 6.0.0, Chrome 30 and higher, and Firefox </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
            <div class="stl_08">
                <span class="stl_05">21 and higher. </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I'm converting from pdf to html, in that pdf file the image comes any where inbetween the text contents.

But by adding this responsiveness the image coming first and then text gets displays, I mean the image is not properly in the same format as it was in pdf, it's misaligned.

How to make Text and Image relative to each other?

Comment: with no example or code it's impossible

Comment: i have edited my question with code

Comment: In here theory reason won't work just show your practical reason then only we can help you.

Comment: @Afreen what about adding some css too? :) www.jsfiddle.net would be best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error i guess is here

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
        <img src="live_files/img_01.svg" class='img-responsive "stl_01"'>
    </div>
</div>
```

it should be

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
        <img src="live_files/img_01.svg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
</div>
```

Check this

http://jsbin.com/loqiwebu/1/

Comment: Iam converting from pdf to html , in that pdf file the image comes any where inbetween the text contents. but by adding this responsivess the image coming first and then ttext gets displays, i mean the image is not properly in the same format as it was in pdf, its misaligned. How to make Text and Image relative to each other. Both are getting reposnive but they are not relative.........